# How to accelerate (parallelize ?) text files into dataframe conversion?

Tags: r, io

I have hundreds of .csv in a folder that I would like to convert into a dataframe in R. I can do this with this code :

```
file_list <- list.files()

dataset = NULL

for (file in file_list){  

    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep=" ")

    temp_dataset$symbol <- unlist(strsplit(file,split=".",fixed=T))[1]

    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)

    print(file)
}
```

But the bigger the dataframe gets the slower new files are added and it rapidly becomes consequent. My entire folder is only 300mb so it's still manageable by R. Is there a way to accelerate the process ?

Comment: You are commiting the [cardinal sin](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) of growing an object in a loop. Do something like this instead: `dataset  <- lapply(file_list, function(file) <...>); dataset <- do.call(rbind, dataset)` Using package data.table could make this even faster.

Comment: @Roland : is there a way to print files that are currently processed into the list by lapply ? Some text files are ill formated and make the expression throw an error, I would like to know which ones are bad.

Comment: Use `trycatch` , or if you know what sort of formatting problems exist, just check for that specific condition, e.g. `if(length(temp_dataset$symbol ==0 ) do_something` . Parallelization almost certainly won't help, as you'll blow a ton of time piping each `temp_dataset` back to the main process.

Comment: @Wicelo Just add `message(file)` to the function body.